# Are the jobs offers showing Gross salary or Net?

Tags: support, status-completed, stack-overflow-jobs

Sorry for this stupid question, but I really have no idea.

Maybe it depends on company that offers a job? Or maybe on SO there is a rule, to show Gross salary or in the other way?

My quess is Gross, but I am not sure.

Comment: It'd be gross. The net amount is dependent on your own circumstances and tax liabilities etc... (so it'll vary by person and by country etc...)

Comment: I contacted StackOverflow support with a request to clear it. We all are developers, we hate when something is AMBIGUOUS :) Especially when it is so important.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

It's entirely up to the employer but, as Jon indicates in the comments, it wouldn't make a lot of sense to be net as this differs based upon individual circumstances.

Generally speaking employers put a gross annual salary. We have a few edge cases where they put hourly or monthly values - we're working to weed those out and make everything consistent, but even then it'll be gross.